# what is the difference between types atomic_int_fastN_t and atomic_int_leastN_t

Tags: c++, c++11

On [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/) What I see the data types  `atomic_int_fastN_t`  and `atomic_int_leastN_t` where N could be 8,16,32 and 64. So what is the meaning of word least and fast in the them or how they differ? i.e. How `atomic_int_fast64_t` is different from at `atomic_int_least64_t` and `atomic<int64_t>` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The same principle applies as to the non-atomic typedefs: `std::int_least64_t`, `std::int_fast32_t` etc.

The "least*n*" types are those whose size is at least *n* bits. It can be more if the implementation does not support a type of exactly *n* bits.

The "fast*n*" types are those whose size is at least *n* bits, *and* working with them does not require additional operations for the processor (i.e. working with them is fast).

For example, on a 32-bit machine, it's possible that 16-bit integers are supported, but they have to be promoted to 32-bit integers for arithmetic operations, and truncated again once computation is done. On such a machine, `std::int_least16_t` would be the 16-bit integer, but `std::int_fast16_t` wold be a 32-bit integer, since that's what is fast to work with.

The typedef `std::int64_t` is then guaranteed to be *exactly* 64 bits (and will only exist if such an integer is supported by the implementation).

Comment: That last paragraph touches on a little-appreciated detail: The "exact" types (e.g. `int32_t`) *are not guaranteed to exist on any given platform*. Only the `least` and `fast` types are.